# Data content changes when Coredata didsavenotification is received

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

I'm having a terrible problem. I'm saving a managedObject "*Customer*" with field *sync* as `false` using my main MOC. Then after syncing with server, I use a private MOC to save the *Customer* with *sync* field as `true`. When I save this, notification is passed and the main MOC saves the customer correctly. Then when I edit that customer, the same process happens. But this time, even if the *sync* field is `true`, upto the point where private MOC saves it, the notification got at the other end contains *Customer* with *sync* as `false`. If I repeat the process, *sync* becomes `true`. Instead of repeating, if I am saving some other data using the private MOC, then with that notification, *Customer* also comes with *sync* field as `true`. I don't understand why notification method is not working correctly. In `addObserver` of didsavenotification, I have specified the `object` as the private MOC itself. Somebody please help.
These are the code snippets prominent in this flow.

//Assigning false

`selectedCustomer.synced = NSNumber(bool: false)`

//Saving using main MOC

`try managedObjectContext.save()`

//Assigning synced details to a dictionary

`let cust: CustomerDetails = CustomerDetails(data: customer)
 cust.synced = true`

//Assigning dictionary to customer managedObject fetched from coredata using private MOC

`assignData(customerDetails, toCustomer: customer)`

//Saving the private MOC

`try syncManagedObjectContext.save()`

//Getting notification and saving

`managedObjectContext.performBlock { () -> Void in                    self.managedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
}`

//Registration of notification

`let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.managedObjectContextDidSave(_:)), name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: syncManagedObjectContext)`

**EDIT:**

These are the definitions of the MOCs I'm using

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

lazy var syncManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Comment: Probably need to show the code around how your saving both times

Answer (score 1):

Show how you defined your MOCs as well.

Are they parent child?

Are they siblings against the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`?

This can have an impact.

I would also turn on `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` and run your app again as this sounds like a threading issue.

### Update 1

As your `NSManagedObjectContext` instances are siblings you really need to turn on the currency debug flag and run again.  This really reads like a threading issue.

### Update 2

There is not a lot of code in your question to try and deduce an answer if this is not a threading issue.

My next suggestion would be to move your private MOC from a sibling to a child (Apple's documentation on threading discusses this) and stop using the notification (unnecessary with child MOCs).

If the issue is still there then you are going to need to trace it in the debugger and find out at what point the issue surfaces.  It can still be a threading issue without being a "touched the wrong object on the wrong thread" issue.  Is the property being changed when you think it is?  Using the debugger is the only way to be certain.

Comment: I tried running with concurrency debug flag and found many flaws in my code. Thank you:-) But the problem I pointed out in this question is still there. There are no other errors coming up now. Could you please give me some good reference to study about this siblings, multi threading and notification method?